# bxslider - make max-height is possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider

I want to ask many questions about bxslider
now the bxslider is max-width 100% to make responsive

1. however, if it is possible to make slide max-height to be 100%?
2. I not add only image (add HTML such as div) is it possible to do responsive? or adding more responsive css for html inside bxslide?
3. I know that it has option auto slide. but when I click to see the next image, it doesn't auto slide anymore. Can it make to auto slide again?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. for the height there is no oprion for max-height:100%, but also you can use adaptiveHeight:true/false for .. True option is dynamically adjust slider height based on each slide's height
2. you need to style your div for responsive view, just for example you can can give width and height with percentage, or with vw vh properties

3.if you will give an option like auto:true , it will work the way you need I think..

if have more questions, just ping here.. will try to help as I am veteran in bxSlider :)